# React Native: The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to upgrade react-native project from 0.64 to latest. I did replaced most of the outdated packages to the latest and so far so good.

When I try to run npx react-native run-android, error at the below pops out.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'SsNative'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I am currently hitting all the buttons to pass this error. But no luck at all.
I guess some of the native packages or any other package using toolchain feature somehow but event I tried with jdk-11 and jdk-17 error still the same.

My root build.gradle;

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
       buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
       google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

And android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.rndiffapp"
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ssnative"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 34
        versionName "1.9.4"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

I copied gradle files from a new project because old gradle files are completely off. Somehow winded up here and  got stuck, there is not enough solutions on so or any other place for that error.

Thank you.

**Solution-ish:**
This issue got resolved by itself when I upgraded gradle version >8.3.
I don't have any idea if its related to the gradle version or not.

Comment: Same problem and I need to resolve it urgently!

Comment: I guess you need to update gradle version from gradle-wrapper.properties to latest. Right now I changed it to 8.3 and app started working. But all icons and gone and tabs inside app coming empty. @BackupGov18

Answer (score 1):

In my case, mac got updated to latest jdk automatically, that was the root cause. I had to do the following in my local to get it to work and ensure it was running as expected in production.

---

1. Changed the following in `PROJECT_ROOT/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

---

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
```

to (latest gradle)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip
```

---

2. Added the following in `PROJECT_ROOT/build.gradle` (ensures production works until its upgraded to 21)

---

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(19))
    }
}
```